# Docker drive has no space left even though there's loads of space in the container

Tags: r, docker, shiny, shiny-server

I'm working with Shiny-Server in Docker for Windows. The problem I've encountered is when I run `docker-compose up`, it doesn't copy across all the files from my working directory on Windows to the Docker container. This appears to be because the drive on the Docker container is full, as I can't copy them across manually with `docker cp . <container_id>:srv/shiny-server/apps` either - I get a "no space left on device" error.

Within the container, doing `df` returns the following:

[100% of /srv/shiny-server/apps folder used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EToyn.png)

which shows that 100% of the drive which is mounted on "srv/shiny-server/apps" is in use. It's only 897M yet there's some 11G free on other drives.

Why is it limiting the size of that drive such that I can't copy all of the files across, even though the entire docker container is large enough?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
docker system df -v
```

This shows detailed information on space usage.

As a temporary solution to get space, you could remove all the images, volumes and networks, etc in your docker. You could use this (be careful!!!!, because is going to delete everything in docker).

```
docker system prune -af
```

You can find other options here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/